# How to set Joomla template for user/visit

Tags: templates, session, joomla

I want to use specific Joomla template (with no navigation, no top and bottom) for users that connect to website through my mobile app with iframe in it. I assume that this users will start connection from specific address with tmpl param (or something similar) but is there a way to lock this template for these users?

Maybe there is some plugin to set template in session data and override default template choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin allows me to set template only for specyfic user group, not to switch template accordingly to url but thanks to Your idea I created very simple plugin to do this, code below:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class plgSystemMobiler extends JPlugin
{
    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $jinput = $app->input;

        if (isset($_REQUEST['mobile'])) $par=(int)$_REQUEST['mobile'];
        if (isset($par)) $jinput->cookie->set('mobile', $par, time() + 100000, $app->get('cookie_path', '/'), $app->get('cookie_domain'), $app->isSSLConnection());

        $cookie=$jinput->cookie->get('mobile');
        if (intval($cookie)>0) JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('templateStyle', intval($cookie));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Joomla extension called Template Assigner - http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/template-assigner . It does exactly what you want.